# Read MAX value from db and avoid null, using ExecuteScalar

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

How do I avoid null and instead get integer 0?

```
 cmd.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(*) " +
                   "FROM [Test] " +
                   "WHERE ID = @id ;"; 

 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ID);
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 Amount = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: just check result of cmd.ExecuteScalar for null (or DbNull.Value) and set Amount to 0 in this case

Comment: `SELECT MAX(*)`?? What is this supposed to be? You need to specify a column name. Also, ID columns usually mark primary key columns hence they are unique. Using the `MAX` function doesn't make sense when your WHERE clause limits the result list to 0 or 1 elements. Some basics: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_max.asp

Comment: @QualityCatalyst Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first you must specify column which you want calcul MAX `SELECT MAX(column_name)` and you can use this :

```
object obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

Amount = (obj != null && obj != DBNull.Value) ? Convert.ToInt32(obj) : 0 ;
```